# ESP32 webserver - reading data from text field

Tags: esp32

I am absolutely new to this and need some help. I am working on a door lock that can connect to the network and work with the database to sort access and whatnot.

And I am creating an access point mode in which the user can go to the page provided by the ESP32 and set SSID and password of his own network that the ESP32 will then remember - I can create the web, I can create a text field, and submit button but I have no idea how to read that data the user inputted and save it in my variables.

Can you refer me to some website where I can read more about it?

Comment: remember even after reboot => eeprom.getting user form submission => post.

Comment: you should read about HTTP POST requests, this is the way html forms work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to go the Arduino/PlatformIO or ESP-IDF route?  (For student/hobby Arduino is good, but for professional products I recommend ESP-IDF.)

https://github.com/chmorgan/esphttpd-freertos is a decent working example of WiFi provisioning via ESP-hosted webserver.
It is also a good starting platform to build your app from (it's what I use).